# How can I use Power Automate to move data from one Excel file to the other?

Tags: excel, power-automate

I want to create a simple flow that does the following:

1. When a file is created in OneDrive,
2. If it ends with .xlsx
3. Get rows from this file's Table1
4. Add rows to the Master file
5. Move it to another folder.

That's it. I've tried "apply to each", I've tried a direct add a row, nothing is working (and I believe it's because I don't know what to put in the column fields in the "Add a row to a table" card.) I know the main flow works because in the end, the file is moved, but there are no new rows int he Master file. I attached two of the flows I tried for clarity (both of which failed.)

[First try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3h2I.png)

[Second Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxGr9.png)

Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, it sounds like you're trying to implement what is effectively a database in Excel. You wouldn't be the first one to do that, but ultimately you can save yourself a lot of headaches by going ahead and setting up a database anyway. Importing data from Excel files into those is a very common task with a lot of support, as is exporting the data to be available in Excel again (or through a direct connection, or Power BI). You can still keep the Excel files around for reference/redoing imports, but using them for long-term storage with a fixed schema is asking for trouble.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Interesting insight, and I agree. However, I was tasked to make this possible and that decision is ultimately not up to me - it's my supervisor's decision. If you have any pointers on how I can build the flow please share!